# Are there surahs in the quran which state that the moon is lit by reflected sunlight?

Tags: quran, science, quran-translation, arabic-translation

When I look up at the moon at night, it looks like a source of its own light just like the sun. [surah 71:16](https://quran.com/71/16-26) expresses this observation as:

> And made the moon therein a [reflected] light and made the sun a burning lamp?

The [reflected] has been added and isn't part of the surah, so I'm looking for a surah that contains the word *reflected* or something similar to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Quran does not explicitly say that the moon is lit by reflected sunlight. Also see [related answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/47537/20218).

Answer (score 1):

The answer of this question is **yes** the Qur'an describes the moon as a corpus that is lit, but **no** it doesn't explicitly say it is lit by reflected sunlight.

There are a couple of verses that describe the "light" or kind of lightening or illumination of the sun and the moon.

- > It is He who made the sun a shining light and the moon a derived light and determined for it phases - ... ([10:5](https://legacy.quran.com/10/5))
- > And made the moon therein a [reflected] light and made the sun a burning lamp? ([71:16](https://legacy.quran.com/71/16))

and a rather indirectly in:

- > And constructed above you seven strong [heavens] (12) And made [therein] a burning lamp ([78:12-13](https://legacy.quran.com/78/12-13))

In these verses the attribute or example of the moon was that of a النور (an-Nur) which refers in Arabic to anything that is opposed to darkness (ضدّ الظُّلمة ) and anything that makes things visible ([Source: معجم المعاني الجامع  -](https://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%88%D8%B1/) ما يُبَيِّن الأشْياءَ ويُرِي الأبْصَارَ حقيقتها ).
While the sun has been named الضياء (a-Dyaa' coming from ad-Daw'u الضوء which is a synonym of an-Nur at least when we don't want to be too specific ) and [السراج](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AC/) (as-Siraj) which actually is an oil lamp (that gives light). Note that the term ad-Diya' refers toa source of light or something that gives light!

Here a statement from the dictionary  [قاموس المعجم الوسيط](https://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B6%D9%88%D8%A1/)

> الضَّوْءُ  : النُّورُ . 
>   وهما مُتَرَادِفانِ ، أَو  الضوءُ  أَقوى وأَسطعُ من النورِ ، أَو  الضوء  لما بالذاتِ كضوءِ الشمس والنارِ ، والنورُ لما بالعَرَضِ والاكتساب من جسم آخر
>
> Ad-Daw'u: an-Nur and they are synonyms or ad-Daw'(u) is stronger and brighter than an-Nur or ad-Daw'(u) refers to anything that gives a light byitself like the sun and the fire while an-Nur appears as giving light or reflects it from another source (corpus).

The Qur'an therefore makes a distinction between sun and moon saying the sun is a source of light while the moon is a corpus that appears as giving light or reflects light, but it does not say that the reflected light actually is sunlight.